# Build fails when using file picker but when I use file_picker version less then 2.0.0 it works

Tags: file, picker

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
Android resource linking failed
D:\Working\flutter projects\todo_app\android\projects\todo_app\build\file_picker\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-15:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element found in .

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin file_picker...
Checking the license for package SDK Patch Applier v4 in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\licenses
Warning: License for package SDK Patch Applier v4 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android Emulator in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\licenses
Warning: License for package Android Emulator not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform-Tools in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform-Tools not accepted.